# Geo-dispersed/replicated Azure database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, azure, replication

I'm configuring an application that will reach multiple global geographies. The application will use Azure database for MySQL, but it looks like I can only deploy that in one region.

I'm not as concerned about availability since it is available 99.99% and I am fine with the redundant storage backup options.

Latency is my biggest question. Has anyone had to connect servers in North America to a centralized DB is Europe or Japan? It is a transactional application, but load is not excessive.

Is there even an option for synchronous replication of Azure Database for MySQL from Europe to North America? What are alternatives in such a scenario?

Comment: You should look at CosmosDB. Also, this is very helpful: https://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @CSharpRocks Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm working with some COTS software and CosmosDB is not supported. I was looking at Azure DB for MySQL to try and go serverless at the data tier. Save myself some infrasructure and DB headaches.